# Subir imagenes con Angular y Python a directorio

Tags: python-3.x, angular, web, aplicación-web

Estoy haciendo una app web con `angular` de frontend y `python3`(flask) de backend.

En el frontend tengo un formulario donde uno de los campos va a ser una sola imagen, lo que preciso es que se le envié a mi API, y que la reciba el servidor para almacenarla en un directorio especifico, así también que en mi Base de Datos se almacene el path para luego yo poder mostrarlo en otro componente.

En el component.html tengo:

```
<input type="file" (change)="cargandoImagen($event)">
```

En component.ts tengo:

```
public respuestaImagenEnviada;
public resultadoCarga;
public cargandoImagen(files: FileList){

  this.orderService.postFileImagen(files[0]).subscribe(

    response => {
      this.respuestaImagenEnviada = response; 
      if(this.respuestaImagenEnviada <= 1){
        console.log("Error en el servidor"); 
      }else{

        if(this.respuestaImagenEnviada.code == 200 && this.respuestaImagenEnviada.status == "success"){

          this.resultadoCarga = 1;

        }else{
          this.resultadoCarga = 2;
        }

      }
    },
    error => {
      console.log(<any>error);
    }

  )
```

Y en el service.ts tengo

```
public postFileImagen(imagenParaSubir: File){

    const formData = new FormData(); 
    formData.append('imagenPropia', imagenParaSubir, imagenParaSubir.name); 
    return this.http.post(this.API_URI, formData);

}
```

Mi pregunta es:

> esta bien asi?
>   Y que deberia hacer para desde el back guardarla en un directorio y poder tomar el path para luego guardarla en la BD?